# Is there a way to generate or get tempQueryId from Copy Query URL in TFS query editor?

Tags: azure, tfs, wiquery

In previous version I had a functionaly to download a .wiq file and it opens inside visual studio. From there I could go to web version of query editor.

Link is similar to: http://tfs/_queries/query/?tempQueryId={Guid}&resultsEditorContext=query-edit

For now application is a TFS extension and I want to open web query editor from there.

So the problem is how to get or generate this tempQueryId.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Hi Andrew, any update on this thread, do you still have concern with it. Just checking to see if the information provided was helpful. If my reply helped or gave a right direction. Appreciate for marking it as an which will also helps others in the community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At present, you still could be able to download the `.wiq` file.

1. Select the Edit query wiql

[image]

2. In the pop-up web dialog, click Export

[image]

3. Choose save it will be download as `New Query 1.wiq` in local file system

[image]

Besides, there are two ways to share a query, [Email query items or share a query URL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/view-run-query?view=azure-devops#email-query-items-or-share-a-query-url).

If share a query with **Copy query URL**, it will generate **a temp query id**, which is not allow others to access the query path. This should be the same temp query ID which you mentioned.

However, there isn’t the method or property to get the temp query id. Also, from collection database, there isn’t the table for that information too. Take a look at this similar question [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/183e5a6a-4727-4949-9b68-2b2080b6810e/how-to-use-tempqueryid-from-the-quotcopy-query-urlquot-generated-link-to-get-the-query-file?forum=tfsgeneral).